# Proving trigonometric problem from given trigonometric equations

Tags: trigonometry

If $p$ & $q$ are the solutions of $$a \cos x + b \sin x = c$$

Then how do I prove that, $$\cos (p + q) = \dfrac{a^2-b^2}{a^2 + b^2} $$

I tried all the adjustments I could think of, like dividing by $ \cos x $ and extracting $a$ and $b$ from the 2 equations. Also tried adding/subtracting and all the basics I know to no avail.

Any help is appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: I think you should review the variable names ;-)

Comment: What are $\alpha$ and $\beta$ w.r.t.  $p$ and $q$? And why are there only two solutions for $x$?

Comment: @Yves Daoust Yes Sir! Corrected. It was a typing error.

Comment: Are there any conditions on $a,b,c$?

Comment: “The” solutions? The equation has infinitely many solutions in real numbers. Perhaps you were meant to restrict its domain to one cycle.

Comment: @David K I think you're correct! I thought of that too, but as my text book didn't mention any conditions, I wrote it here the way it is, just to be safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given
$$
a\cos x + b\sin x = c
$$
put
$$
A = \sqrt {a^{\,2}  + b^{\,2} } \quad \phi  = \arctan \left( {{b \over a}} \right)
$$
to get
$$
\eqalign{
  & c = a\cos x + b\sin x = A\cos \phi \cos x + A\sin \phi \sin x =   \cr 
  &  = A\cos \left( {x - \phi } \right) = A\cos \left( {p - \phi } \right) = A\cos \left( {q - \phi } \right) \cr} 
$$
from which you obtain
$$
A\cos \left( {p - \phi } \right) = A\cos \left( {q - \phi } \right)\quad  \Rightarrow \quad p - \phi  =  - \left( {q - \phi } \right)\quad  \Rightarrow \quad p + q = 2\phi 
$$
(apart from multiples of $2\pi$).

The rest you should do easily by yourself, I suppose.

Comment: Awesome..... +1

Comment: @William: glad to help, and remember that the linear combination of two sinusoids into a single one (with proper amplitude and phase) is quite a useful "trick" in many occasions.

Answer (score 6):

We have

$$c-a\cos x=b\sin x$$ and by squaring and rewriting,

$$c^2-2ac\cos x+a^2\cos^2x=b^2(1-\cos^2x),$$
$$(a^2+b^2)\cos^2x-2ac\cos x+c^2-b^2=0.$$

Using the Vieta's formulas, the product of the roots is

$$\cos p\cos q=\frac{c^2-b^2}{a^2+b^2}.$$
Repeating the same reasoning symmetrically,

$$\sin p\sin q=\frac{c^2-a^2}{a^2+b^2}.$$

Now by subtraction,

$$\cos(p+q)=\frac{a^2-b^2}{a^2+b^2}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Y'all no worries! I figured it out – (by a fluke?), I just want someone to confirm this is right :)

Converting to it to original question in my textbook. Let $p= \alpha$ and $q = \beta$

$\alpha$ and $\beta$ are solutions of $a\cos\theta+b\sin\theta=c$

$$a\cos\alpha+b\sin\alpha=c=a\cos\beta+b\sin\beta $$

$$b(\sin\alpha-\sin\beta)=-a(\cos\alpha-\cos\beta)$$

$$ 2b\cos\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right)=2a\sin\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right)$$

$$\frac{b}{a}=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right)}{\cos\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right)}=\tan\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right) $$

$$ \tan^2\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)=\frac{b^2}{a^2}$$

$$\cos(\alpha+\beta)=\frac{\cos^2\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)-\sin^2\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)}{\cos^2\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)+\sin^2\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)}$$

Dividing the numerator and denominator by $\cos^2\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)$ , we get,

$$\cos(\alpha+\beta)=\frac{1-\tan^2\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)}{1+\tan^2\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)}=\frac{1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}}{1+\frac{b^2}{a^2}}$$

$$\Rightarrow\qquad \cos(\alpha+\beta)=\frac{a^2-b^2}{a^2+b^2}$$

Thanks to everyone for their efforts :-)

Comment: Your answer is correct :)